# Consider the nonlinear first order equation $y' = x − y^2$. If y(x) = $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ , find a recurrence relation for the $a_n$’s.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In part a of the problem, I proved that $y'' = 1-2xy+2y^3$ and $y'' = 1 - 2yy'$.

Then in part b, I showed that if $y(0) = 1$ and $y(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty y^(n)(0)x^n/(n!)$, $y(x) = 1 - x + (3/2)x^2 - (8/6)x^3+...$.

But now I don't know where to continue for part c:
Consider the nonlinear first order equation $y' = x − y^2$.  If y(x) = $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$, find a recurrence relation for the $a_n$’s.

I'm unsure in which differential equation I should be plugging in derivatives of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$.

The original differential equation has an x term, and both of the y'' equations contain either multiplication or cubing of a summation.

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write, from definition, $$y=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{y^{(n)}}{n!}x^n$$ Now, the differential equation $$y' = x − y^2$$ and we continue differentiating $$y''=1-2y\,y'$$ $$y'''=-2y'^2-2y\,y''$$ $$y^{(4)}=-6y'y''-2y\, y'''$$ and so forth.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where to proceed because of the double summation.
$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_{n+3}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)x^n + 2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2(a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n)^2 + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2(a_nx^n)(a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n) = 0$